# Node cli on Msysgit on WIndows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, msysgit

I recently decided to pick up Node on my personal laptop, which I upgraded to Windows 10, and the Node cli seems to hang when I try to run it.

Simply typing `node` on the console will not initiate the interface, and to do anything else I need to Ctrl+C out of it.

Additionally, running some npm commands take longer than they used to on my laptop. More noticeably, `npm init` seems to hang after confirming the information to be written to package.json.

Node version is 4.0.0
npm version is 2.14.2

Are there any known issues with Node and npm on Windows 10?

Edit: 
After some troubleshooting, I've figured out the error only happens on Msysgit. Neither of the issues happen on the standard command prompt of Windows.

Comment: Must be a local issue, I have Windows 10 and there are no issues with Node.js on my machine

Comment: @beautifulcoder Did you update to Node 4.0.0?

Comment: Yep, no issues at all

Comment: My `npm` version is 2.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on Windows 7 with Node version 6.11.0 and Msysgit's MINGW64 terminal window.

The problem was caused by the an alias provided by Msysgit as demonstrated below:

```
$ alias node
alias node='winpty node.exe'
```

The solution is to run the command:

```
$ unalias node
```

Then node will run correctly.

You can add the `unalias node` command into your `.bashrc` file in your HOME directory to make this permanent.

Good luck!
Jeff